# autocomplete jquery with ajax unable to populate

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery. I am trying to put together autocomplete feature for a text field. So far I am able to take the input, make a ajax call, get the json response and build an array with data . However, I am unable to present in that data in autocomplete. Here is my javascript code. I am not sure if its a css issue or a javascript issue. I have added jquery-ui.css.
Please advise.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        function SearchText() {
            $("#text-drug").autocomplete({
                minLength: 3, 
                source: function(request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "url",
                        beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
                            xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data != null) {
                            var parsedJson = $.parseJSON(data);
                            alert(parsedJson);
                            var arr = [];
                            for (var i=0;i<parsedJson.length;++i)
                                {
                                    arr.push(parsedJson[i].name);
                                }
                                alert(arr);
                            response(arr);                                }
                        },
                        error: function(result) {
                            alert("Error");
                        }
                    });
                }

            });
        }
```

});

Comment: This code works fine for me. May be you are checking it without typing 3 characters?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a similar code I tested and it works fine. Please see if it helps you to find the issue with your code.

**1. index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete functionality</title>
      <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <!-- Javascript -->
      <script>
         $(function() {
            $( "#txtAutocomplete" ).autocomplete({
                minLength: 3,
               source: function(request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "data.php",
                        beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
                            xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data != null) {
                            var parsedJson = $.parseJSON(data);
                            //alert(parsedJson);
                            var arr = [];
                            for (var i=0;i<parsedJson.length;++i)
                                {
                                    arr.push(parsedJson[i].name);
                                }
                                //alert(arr);
                            response(arr);                                }
                        },
                        error: function(result) {
                            alert("Error");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- HTML --> 
      <div class="ui-widget">
         <input id="txtAutocomplete">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**2. data.php**

```
<?php
    echo "[{\"name\":\"programmer\"},{\"name\":\"stackoverflow\"}]";
?>
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

You may also need to filter data using term property in request object. Please refer to [JQuery UI Autocomplete Documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) for more information.